# Excel - how to combine values ​from both columns (not in every case)

Tags: excel, prefix

[image]

Hi,

I want to combine value from phone number new and prefix but in some cases prefix just exist, is it any way to eliminate these cells that contains prefix?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work in column I, starting from I2, autofill the formula.

```
= IF(H2= "+"&LEFT(F2,LEN(H2)-1),F2,SUBSTITUTE(H2,"+","")&F2)
```